# Transforming geos_geomtries to sf geometries raises error (Error: Not compatible with STRSXP: [type=NULL])

Tags: r, r-sf, tmap, geos

I've been experimenting with `data.table` + `geos` (see https://grantmcdermott.com/fast-geospatial-datatable-geos/ for the example I followed), but I've had issues converting the `data.table+geos` object back to `sf` (for mapping with `tmap`, for example).

In the reprex below, I take an `sf` object and convert it to a `data.table` with a `geos` column. I combine units on some criteria, and then map the result. This operation works fine with the `nc` data set (first section), but fails using the Digital Tax Map of NYC ([original data](https://data.cityofnewyork.us/Housing-Development/Department-of-Finance-Digital-Tax-Map/smk3-tmxj), [subset used in reprex](https://vinceth.net/assets/dataset/dtm_sf.Rds)). I am also unable to make the converted-back-to-`sf` object valid, or to recast it to `MULTIPOLYGON`. The error message is always `Error: Not compatible with STRSXP: [type=NULL].`.

As mentioned, I'm new to `geos` and mostly experimenting at this stage, so I might be missing something obvious, or doing something very unorthodox — please let me know if that's the case, how I could improve and how to make this work.

```r
library(data.table)
library(geos)
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.11.0, GDAL 3.5.3, PROJ 9.1.0; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
library(tmap)
#> The legacy packages maptools, rgdal, and rgeos, underpinning the sp package,
#> which was just loaded, will retire in October 2023.
#> Please refer to R-spatial evolution reports for details, especially
#> https://r-spatial.org/r/2023/05/15/evolution4.html.
#> It may be desirable to make the sf package available;
#> package maintainers should consider adding sf to Suggests:.
#> The sp package is now running under evolution status 2
#>      (status 2 uses the sf package in place of rgdal)

# NC: maps fine ----

nc = st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package = "sf"))
#> Reading layer `nc' from data source 
#>   `/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.3-arm64/Resources/library/sf/shape/nc.shp' 
#>   using driver `ESRI Shapefile'
#> Simple feature collection with 100 features and 14 fields
#> Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -84.32385 ymin: 33.88199 xmax: -75.45698 ymax: 36.58965
#> Geodetic CRS:  NAD27
nc_dt = as.data.table(nc)[, geo := as_geos_geometry(geometry)][, geometry := NULL]

nc_div = 
  nc_dt[,
        .(geo = geo |> geos_make_collection() |> geos_unary_union()),
        by = .(region = ifelse(CNTY_ID<=1980, 'high', 'low'))]

tmap_mode("plot")
#> tmap mode set to plotting
tm_shape(st_as_sf(nc_div)) + tm_polygons()
```

[image]

```r
tmap_mode("view")
#> tmap mode set to interactive viewing
tm_shape(st_as_sf(nc_div)) + tm_polygons()
```

[image]

```r
# Sample of NYC Digital Tax Map: doesn't map ----

dtm_sf = readRDS("dtm_sf.Rds")
dtm_dt = as.data.table(dtm_sf)[, geo := as_geos_geometry(geometry)][, geometry := NULL]

dtm_consolidate = 
  dtm_dt[,
         .(geo = geo |> geos_make_collection() |> geos_unary_union()),
         by = .(boro, block, lot)]

dtm_consolidate_sf = st_as_sf(dtm_consolidate)

plot(dtm_consolidate[, geo])
```

[image]

```r
tmap_mode("plot")
#> tmap mode set to plotting
tm_shape(dtm_consolidate_sf) + tm_polygons()
```

[image]

```r
tmap_mode("view")
#> tmap mode set to interactive viewing
tm_shape(dtm_consolidate_sf) + tm_polygons()
#> Error: Not compatible with STRSXP: [type=NULL].

class(st_geometry(dtm_consolidate_sf))
#> [1] "sfc_GEOMETRY" "sfc"
table(st_geometry_type(dtm_consolidate_sf))
#> 
#>           GEOMETRY              POINT         LINESTRING            POLYGON 
#>                  0                  0                  0                 30 
#>         MULTIPOINT    MULTILINESTRING       MULTIPOLYGON GEOMETRYCOLLECTION 
#>                  0                  0                 36                  0 
#>     CIRCULARSTRING      COMPOUNDCURVE       CURVEPOLYGON         MULTICURVE 
#>                  0                  0                  0                  0 
#>       MULTISURFACE              CURVE            SURFACE  POLYHEDRALSURFACE 
#>                  0                  0                  0                  0 
#>                TIN           TRIANGLE 
#>                  0                  0

dtm_consolidate_sf_mltp = dtm_consolidate_sf |> st_cast("MULTIPOLYGON")
#> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos): Not compatible with STRSXP: [type=NULL].
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>